# Adding sidebar chat to bootstrap 3?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make sidebar chat for boostrap 3, something like this

[image]

To be always at the right, and when click to be opened from right to left,

[image]

And when user clikc to be opened, i dont need the styling i can modified the css later, only needed functionality

Can someone just help me for basic funcionality?

This is what i have for now

```
  <div class="row chat-window col-xs-5 col-md-3" id="chat_window_1" style="margin-left:10px;">
  <i id="chat-open" class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-md-11 pull-right">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading top-bar">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                        <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat - Miguel</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="panel-body msg_container_base">
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_sent">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_receive">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_receive">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_sent">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_receive">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10">
                            <div class="messages msg_receive">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row msg_container base_sent">
                        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 ">
                            <div class="messages msg_sent">
                                <p>that mongodb thing looks good, huh?
                                tiny master db, and huge document store</p>
                                <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Timothy • 51 min</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 avatar">
                            <img src="http://www.bitrebels.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Original-Facebook-Geek-Profile-Avatar-1.jpg" class=" img-responsive ">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.chat-window{
    top:300px;
    position:fixed;
    float:right;
    margin-left:10px;
    right: -417px;
}
.chat-window > div > .panel{
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.icon_minim{
    padding:2px 10px;
}
.msg_container_base{
  background: #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  max-height:300px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.top-bar {
  background: #666;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.msg_receive{
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left:0;
}
.msg_sent{
    padding-bottom:20px !important;
    margin-right:0;
}
.messages {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width:100%;
}
.messages > p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 0 0.2rem 0;
  }
.messages > time {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ccc;
}
.msg_container {
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.avatar {
    position: relative;
}
.base_receive > .avatar:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid #FFF;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.base_sent {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.base_sent > .avatar:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(black, 0.2); // not quite perfect but close
}

.msg_sent > time{
    float: right;
}



.msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.msg_container_base::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}

.visible{
  right:0px !important;
}
```

What i need is to hide chat on right, and when click on icon to chat show, and again on icon to hide?

Here is 
JS

```
$( "#chat-open" ).click(function() {
$('#chat_window_1').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

The problem is that thsi way chat only pop up, is it possible to add sime nice slide animation from right to left?

Here is working bootply
http://www.bootply.com/ZTdXhZGi1d

**SOLUTION**

```
$("#chat-open").click(function() {
  if ($('#chat_window_1').css('right') == "0px") {
    $('#chat_window_1').animate({right: "-417px"}, 1200);
  } else {
    $('#chat_window_1').animate({right: "0px"}, 1200);
  }
});
```

Comment: Added working fiddle, but still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `position:fixed` div.

With jQuery you can animate the div 's fixed position.

```
#chat {
  position:fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:20px;
  height:300px
}
```

And some jQuery:

```
$("#chat").click(function() {
  if ($(this).css('right') == "200px") {
    $(this).animate({right: "10px"}, 1200);
  } else {
    $(this).animate({right: "200px"}, 1200);
  }
});
```

Inside the #chat div you can place another div so the div will not close when you click the chat itself.

Comment: Didn't test, try again. Removed the dubble ) in the IF.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/ujfotpdv/1/) and adapt to your needs.

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ccf;
    right: -80px;
}
.visible {
    right: 0px !important;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#sidebar').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Edit:
After including [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) in your page you can animate by passing a duration to the [toggleClass()](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleclass/) function:

```
$(this).toggleClass('visible', 500);
```

Comment: How to add animation to this?

Comment: You can animate the [toggleClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleclass/) function by including jQueryUI in your page and passing a `duration` parameter.